# Recurrence relation question. Homework.

Tags: recurrence-relations

A certain counting sequence $T(n)$ has generating function
$$\frac{x}{1-3x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}T(n)x^n.$$

(a) Derive a simple recurrence relation for $T(n)$.

(b) Give a simple explicit formula for $T(n)$.

I've only studied the fibonacci sequence in class in terms of recurrence relations but I cant see how it links to this question. Any resources that can help me do questions like these?

Comment: Do you know how to expand $1/(1-3x)$ in a series of powers of $x$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Unfortunately no

Comment: Then drop that class before it's too late. See your teacher. Meanwhile, brush up on the formula for the sum of a geometric series.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Ive been doing this course for a whole semester, my final exam is in 5 days. Surely this can't be that hard to understand

Comment: It's easy to understand --- if you have any familiarity with power series. But if you have no idea how to expand $1/(1-3x)$ in a power series, you don't have a snowball's chance of getting generating functions. Please, talk to your teacher.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Hi, I just finished my semester and wanted to let you know I got a B despite you telling me I should drop the course.

Comment: Congratulations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Robert Israel has already given a good hint for (a). You can also solve (a) by first solving (b) to get a closed form for $T(n)$ and then constructing a recurrence from that.

From the formula for the sum of a geometric series you should know that

$$\frac1{1-3x}=\sum_{n\ge 0}(3x)^n=\sum_{n\ge 0}3^nx^n\;,$$

so

$$\sum_{n\ge 0}T(n)x^n=\frac{x}{1-3x}=\ldots\;?$$

Comment: I did some working and got 3^(n-1)?

Comment: @Clay: That’s right for $n\ge 1$, but not for $T(0)$. Can you see what $T(0)$ is?

Comment: should be 0, and T(1) should be 1 I think

Comment: @Clay: Yes, $T(0)=0$, because the constant term of the series expansion of $\frac{x}{1-3x}$ is $0$. And $T(1)=3^{1-1}=1$ from the general formula that applies when $n\ge 1$.

Comment: thanks for the help, you made this question a lot clearer =D

Comment: @Clay: You’re welcome; glad to have been of use.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Multiply the equation by $1-3x$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{x}{1-3x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}T(n)x^n.$$
$$\frac{x}{1-3x}=x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(3x)^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}3^nx^{n+1}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}3^{n-1}x^{n}$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}T(n)x^n=T(0)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}T(n)x^n$$
$$T(0)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}T(n)x^n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}3^{n-1}x^{n}$$ for $T(0)=0$
$$T(n)=3^{n-1},n>0$$